# IF statement picking first option in currency converter (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print "Pound Sterling converter"
print "You can convert pounds to either dollars, euros or yen"

print

dollar = 0
euro = 0
yen = 0

convert_to = input ("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
amount = input("How much would you like to convert? ")

print

if convert_to == dollar:
    amount = amount * 1.3
elif convert_to == euro:
     amount = amount * 1.17
elif convert_to == yen:
    amount = amount * 133.66
else:
    print "You must pick either dollar, euro or yen."

print amount
```

I'm a beginner in Python, as you can probably tell. All I want this program to do is have the user choose a currency (convert_to) and then choose how much they want to convert (amount) and then the program will convert it for them.

When I run the program, the if statement does not work correctly. Instead of seeing what convert_to is, it goes through the convert_to == dollar part regardless of if you type euro or yen. The numbers they are being multiplied by are simply the conversion rates from pounds.

also, a side note but less important one, the final else part does not work. The program brings up a "input not defined" error instead of printing "You must pick either dollar, euro or yen."

Thanks in advance

Comment: All your choice variables are the same values. Change them to different values for each one.

Comment: for `What currency do you want to convert to?` are you expecting a number choice or a string input?

Comment: `dollar` should be `"dollar"` and same for others. `amount` should be `int(amount)`

Comment: What version of python are you using, I assume 2.x? And why do you expect that setting  `dollar`, `euro`, `yen` all equal to `0` would let this work? The only input value that could give a reasonable answer would be `0`. `if/elif/else` works sequentially so it will stop going through the branches once it matches something, so `else` is only active if you enter something other than `0` for `convert_to`

Comment: Side-note: Don't use `input` in Py2. it's unsafe/unreliable since it `eval`s the input string. If the user types `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')`, whelp, better hope the script isn't running as root; even for non-malicious inputs, it's easy to make a silly mistake. Use `raw_input`, and explicitly convert, e.g. use `amount = int(raw_input(...))`. Your `convert_to` `input` just becomes `raw_input` without wrapping, and your tests check for strings, not variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, the user will input either "0", "1" or "2" as a input, for the convertion for dollar, euro or yen respectively. So you need to change the initial values of dollar, euro and yen. Changing that, the version with integer input will work.

```
dollar = 0
euro = 1
yen = 2
```

If the input is a string such as "dollar", "euro" or "yen", the variables need to be changed to these respective strings, so firstly you need to set the variable as:

```
dollar = "dollar"
euro = "euro"
yen = "yen"
```

Then change the input type for raw_input, as python requires this type of input to recognize a String input. So change `convert_to` to:

```
convert_to = raw_input ("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
```

If you try to pass a string to a `input` variable it will always return 0. And since the initial values for all the variable are 0, the if statements returns true when comparing `convert_to` to `dollar` , `euro` or `yen`. Because the comparsion to the dollar is hapening first, it always goes to that case.
These are the changes necessary for the code to run.

Extra: You also don't need the variables in this case, since you're only using them in one field. So on your if statements, you can just compare them to the specific strings, as:

```
if convert_to == "dollars":
    amount *= 1.3
elif convert_to == "euros":
     amount *=  1.17
elif convert_to == "yen":
    amount *= 133.66
else:
    print "You must pick either dollar, euro or yen."
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, changing the values of the variables to different ones work. I was just wondering, why did this work? What was the program doing when all of the values were 0?

Comment: On what input type? Integer or Strings?

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean (forgive my lack of knowledge, I only started a few days ago). I mean when I changed from: dollar = 0, euro = 0, yen = 0 to all of them having different numbers, why did that work?

Comment: The user inputs a number or a name? "0", "1", "2" or "dollar", "string", "yen"?

If they all had the same number, the program would not be able to tell the difference between them, as it compares to the value the variable stores, not the variable name.

Comment: the user inputs the name of the currency, so dollar, euro or yen. I set them  all as zero because without that I was getting an error saying that it was not defined.
edit: I just realised that you are able to enter the value of the currencies and it would still work, so I understand why it didn't work now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change to this:

```
if convert_to == "dollar":
    amount = float(amount) * 1.3
elif convert_to == "euro":
     amount = float(amount) * 1.17
elif convert_to == "yen":
    amount = float(amount) * 133.66
```

There are 2 changes. First one is to set currencies (dollar , euro , yen) to string cause that way it will be possible to compare it with the user's input which will be also a string. Second, amount that is entered by user is string again so we have to convert it to float in order to calculate the converted amount.

Comment: While this answer does answer the question, it might be a good idea to explain your reasoning a bit more. Rather than just saying 'do this'.

Comment: Oh no man, you misunderstood me. I meant put the explanation in **your answer**, not **explain it to me**. I get what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you're assuming that the `input()` function returns an integer. It does not. The `input()` function returns a string, so this:

`convert_to == dollars`

is equal to:

`str == 1`

which will never be true. Just change what you're comparing to to a string. 
Instead of using a variable just say `convert_to == "dollars"`, and so on for the other choices. Also, you must change this line `amount = input("How much would you like to convert? ")` to this `amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))`, so you can get the input as an integer and not a string.

```
print "Pound Sterling converter"
print "You can convert pounds to either dollars, euros or yen"


convert_to = raw_input("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
amount = int(raw_input("How much would you like to convert? "))


if convert_to == "dollars":
    amount *= 1.3
elif convert_to == "euros":
     amount *=  1.17
elif convert_to == "yen":
    amount *= 133.66
else:
    print "You must pick either dollar, euro or yen." 

print amount
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your reply. I pasted your code in to idle and for some reason it returns this error when i try to enter a currency:

convert_to = input ("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dollars' is not defined.


I'm running Python 2.7, could this be the issue?

Comment: @Fred Gimme a sec to check on that

Comment: @Fred are you using strings like in the answer, or do you still have your currency variables? This code should work fine in Python2 and Python3(with the exception of the missing paren's around the print statements)

Comment: @Fred yes, hence why I asked in a comment. `input` in Python 2 will try and evaluate the string as a variable name. Change to `raw_input`

Comment: @Mr.goosberry No, it will throw `NameError` in Python 2, because `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` and so it will look for `dollars`

Comment: @roganjosh yes your right. I forgot that Python2.x has `raw_input` and `input`. I'll change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all dollar, euro and yen have the same start value (0).

I think, you must put different values.

```
dollar = 0
euro = 1
yen = 2
```

Then, you can show amount (print amount) but your calculate value is "amountpython".

Comment: While all of what your saying is true, you're still not mentioning some very important errors and bugs in the OP's code. This is just one of them.

Comment: Many improvements can be made. But the Fred's code runs with this couple of fixes.

Answer (score 0):

In your case dollar, euro and yen , you have initialized to the same value that is zero.
You should assign different values , for example;

```
dollar=0
euro=0
yen=0
```

Then try this

```
print "Pound Sterling converter"
print "You can convert pounds to either dollars, euros or yen"


convert_to = input ("What currency do you want to convert to? ")
amount = int(input("How much would you like to convert? "))


if convert_to == "dollars":
    amount *= 1.3
elif convert_to == "euros":
    amount *=  1.17
elif convert_to == "yen":
    amount *= 133.66
else:
    print "You must pick either dollar, euro or yen." 

print amount
```